# igraph: enumerating triads in a graph and calculating common neighbors for dyads

Tags: python, r, igraph

I'm working with igraph on an undirected graph on two tasks. 
My graph has about 220 million edges.

**Tasks 1:**

I want to get a list of triads in the graph, and there are only two specific types of triads I would want.

1) triangle: A-B-C & A-C 
I guess that can be pretty easily done with "cliques(g, min = 3, max = 3)"

2) A-B-C (A and C not connected)
I'm not sure how this is done, and I want to make sure that in the list B is clearly identified as the broker.

**Task 2**

Once I have the list of triads, I would want to calculate, from the original graph, the number of shared links (or common neighbors) between each pair of node in these triads.

For example: in the following data frame, we have a triangle triad ABC, A and B share 2 common links (C and E); B and C share 1 common link (E), A and C share 1 common link (B)

f1 f2
A  C
B  A
C  B
D  B
E  A
B  E

Can it only be done by intersect() all the nodes got from neighborhood()? Is there are more efficient way?

Many thanks!!